# long comparison

Tags: c, long-integer

I have the following code

```
long x;
scanf("%ld",&x)
if(x==-1) // does this comparison is allowed
    printf("just test\n");
```

does `long` parameters need any casting before comparison?

Comment: The necessity of a cast can be only deduced from some context. Anyway I don't see why `long` would be a special case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-1` is a decimal `int` . There's an implicit conversion (promotion) from `int` to `long`, so `-1` is automatically "casted" to `long`.

Also, both `-1` and `x` are signed types. No need from any additional casts.

Answer (score 3):

As meh said, that's fine. If you want to avoid the "type-anxiety", you *can* make the literal have type `long`:

```
if(x == -1l)
          ^
          |
     lower-case 'L'
    means "long int"
```

But this is a bit anxious-looking in itself, in some contexts.

Comment: Or simply write `-1L`. Lower-case `l` is considered poor style since it looks like the digit 1 on some editor fonts.